# How to force sync git code to specific commit id with command line

Tags: git

I cloned a new repo on my machine with the command 'git clone https://xxx.git C:\git'
Then I want to by force change the code status to specific commit id for example 'fc46f1d', not the latest.
What command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. 
I tried 'git checkout -f commitid'. 
It works as my expectation.